# Change the centering in align environment

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, align, alignment

I recently was trying to figure out a way to get better spacing in an align environment.

Say for example i was trying to type

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=3cm,right=3cm]{geometry} %pour les dimensions
\usepackage{amssymb,stmaryrd,amsmath,mathrsfs,nccmath,mathtools,amsthm,esint,aligned-overset}
%\usepackage{calc,xargs,ifthen} %pour les opérations
\usepackage{graphicx,pdfpages} %pour inclure des images ou des pdf
\usepackage[french]{babel}  %rajouter éventuellemmeent english, greek, etc.
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    %gestion des accents (pour les pdf)
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %encodage du fichier source
\usepackage{fancyhdr} %Used for headers and footers
\usepackage{xcolor} %pour gérer les couleurs
\def\norme#1{\left\lVert\,#1\,\right\rVert}
\def\scal#1#2{\left\langle#1\,,\,#2\right\rangle}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
            \norme{x+y}^2 = \norme{x}^2 + \norme{y}^2 &\iff \scal{x+y}{x+y} = \norme{x}^2+\norme{y}^2 \\
            &\iff \scal{x}{x} + 2\scal{x}{y} + \scal{y}{y} = \scal{x}{x} + \scal{y}{y} \\
            &\iff2\scal{x}{y} = 0 \\
            &\iff\scal{x}{y} = 0 \\
            &\iff x\text{ et }y\text{ orthogonaux}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

The code works, and the display is okay, but the problem is that it looks like this:

[image: Display from the code]

Technically, the equation is centered well, but i was wondering if i could change it so that the `\iff` symbols are in the center of the page, instead of slighty to the left as shown in the picture, and so the result would be

[image: Correct display]

Comment: You probably can but it will require a lot of manual fidling. I would probably use ``\MoveEqLeft \norme{x+y}^2 = \norme{x}^2 + \norme{y}^2 \\`` instead.

Comment: that would not be optimal to have to manually do it each time..., but thanks for the tip

Comment: just note that you are wasting a lot of space under that part of the question. And yes one has to manually add `\MoveEqLeft` when needed

Comment: Note that with your current setup the `\iff` cannot be really centered, the right part of the alignment is too wide (I've tried it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't really, because the r.h.s. of the second row is too long.  However, you can have an approximation with `eqparbox`:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=3cm,right=3cm, showframe]{geometry} %pour les dimensions
\usepackage{amssymb, stmaryrd, mathrsfs, nccmath, mathtools, amsthm, esint, aligned-overset}
\usepackage{graphicx,pdfpages} %pour inclure des images ou des pdf
\usepackage[french]{babel} %rajouter éventuellemmeent english, greek, etc.
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %gestion des accents (pour les pdf)
\usepackage{fancyhdr} %Used for headers and footers
\usepackage{xcolor} %pour gérer les couleurs
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\newcommand{\eqmathbox}[2][M]{\eqmakebox[#1][r]{$\displaystyle#2$}}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norme}\lVert\rVert
\def\scal#1#2{\left\langle#1\,,\,#2\right\rangle}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
            \eqmathbox{\norme{x+y}^2 = \norme{x}^2 + \norme{y}^2} &\iff \eqmathbox{\scal{x+y}{x+y} = \norme{x}^2+\norme{y}^2\hskip 3em} \\
            &\iff \scal{x}{x} + 2\scal{x}{y} + \scal{y}{y} = \scal{x}{x} + \scal{y}{y} \\
            &\iff 2\scal{x}{y} = 0 \\
            &\iff \scal{x}{y} = 0 \\
            &\iff x\text{ et }y\text{ orthogonaux}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]