# Moving the equation to the left in "align"

Tags: math-mode, align, mathtools

Is it possible to move the equation a little bit to the left in the `align` environment?

For example, how to move the following equation to the left so that `\simeq` is approximately on the center?

(*I read [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/588916), but the suggested `\MoveEqLeft` does not quite fit here, and the answer there requires an extra package, so I wonder if there is a simpler way*)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Hom}{Hom}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
    \Hom_C(C \otimes_B (B \otimes_A M), P)
    & \simeq \Hom_B(B \otimes_A M, P)\\
    & \simeq \Hom_A(M, P)\\
    & \simeq \Hom_C(C \otimes_A M, P)
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "so that `\simeq` is approximately on the center". The center of what?

Comment: @Mico I meant the center of the paper (width), but if that is too hard (since the paper size can vary), it can also be just be *e.g.* moving a fixed length to the left.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see little reason to, to be honest.

Measure the two sides and insert the appropriate space (positive or negative).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclareMathOperator{\Hom}{Hom}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\centralize}[3]{%
  \settowidth{\@tempdima}{$\m@th\displaystyle#1$}%
  \settowidth{\@tempdimb}{$\m@th\displaystyle#3$}%
  \hspace*{\dimexpr\@tempdimb-\@tempdima}#1&#2#3%
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\noindent
X\dotfill X\dotfill X
\begin{align*}
  \centralize{\Hom_C(C \otimes_B (B \otimes_A M), P)}{\simeq}{\Hom_B(B \otimes_A M, P)}\\
  & \simeq \Hom_A(M, P)\\
  & \simeq \Hom_C(C \otimes_A M, P)
\end{align*}
X\dotfill X\dotfill X
\begin{align*}
  \centralize{\Hom_C(C, P)}{\simeq}{\Hom_B(B \otimes_A M, P)}\\
  & \simeq \Hom_A(M, P)\\
  & \simeq \Hom_C(C \otimes_A M, P)
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

For more complicated situations, use phantoms.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclareMathOperator{\Hom}{Hom}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\centralize}[3]{%
  \settowidth{\@tempdima}{$\m@th\displaystyle#1$}%
  \settowidth{\@tempdimb}{$\m@th\displaystyle#3$}%
  \hspace*{\dimexpr\@tempdimb-\@tempdima}#1&#2#3%
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\noindent
X\dotfill X\dotfill X
\begin{align*}
  \centralize{\Hom_C(C \otimes_B (B \otimes_A M), P)}{\simeq}{\Hom_B(B \otimes_A M, P)}\\
  & \simeq \Hom_A(M, P)\\
  & \simeq \Hom_C(C \otimes_A M, P)
\end{align*}
X\dotfill X\dotfill X
\begin{align*}
  \Hom_C(C \otimes_B (B \otimes_A M), P)
  & \simeq \Hom_B(B \otimes_A M, P)\\
  & \simeq \Hom_A(M, P)\\
  & \simeq \Hom_C(C \otimes_A M, P) \\
  \centralize{\hphantom{\Hom_C(C \otimes_B (B \otimes_A M), P)}}
             {\simeq}{xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}
\end{align*}
X\dotfill X\dotfill X
\begin{align*}
  \centralize{\Hom_C(C, P)}{\simeq}{\Hom_B(B \otimes_A M, P)}\\
  & \simeq \Hom_A(M, P)\\
  & \simeq \Hom_C(C \otimes_A M, P)
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If you want to have the ≃ character exactly in the center without any random dimensions explicitly set, then you can define your own align macro `\calign` based on `\halign` primitive TeX command and `\tabskip` primitive register.

```
\def\calign#1{\tabskip=0pt plus1fill
   \halign to\hsize{\llap{$\displaystyle##$}\tabskip=0pt &%
      $\displaystyle{}##{}$&\rlap{$\displaystyle##$}\tabskip=0pt plus1fill\cr
      #1\crcr}%
}

\def\Hom{\mathop{\rm Hom}\nolimits}

\noindent X\dotfill Y
$$
\calign{
   \Hom_C(C ⊗_B (B ⊗_A M), P) & ≃ & \Hom_B(B ⊗_A M, P)\cr
                              & ≃ & \Hom_A(M, P)\cr
                              & ≃ & \Hom_C(C ⊗_A M, P)
}
$$
X\dotfill Y

\noindent X\dotfill Y\dotfill Z
```

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Hom}{Hom}

\begin{document}


\noindent X\dotfill X
\begin{align*}
    \Hom_C(C \otimes_B (B \otimes_A M), P)
    & \simeq \Hom_B(B \otimes_A M, P)\\
    & \simeq \Hom_A(M, P)\\
    & \simeq \Hom_C(C \otimes_A M, P)
\end{align*}

\noindent X\dotfill X
\begin{align*}
    \hspace*{-2cm}\Hom_C(C \otimes_B (B \otimes_A M), P)
    & \simeq \Hom_B(B \otimes_A M, P)\\
    & \simeq \Hom_A(M, P)\\
    & \simeq \Hom_C(C \otimes_A M, P)
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

The `\hspace` isn't directly moving the alignment, but it affects the effective size of the first cell which causes the modified placement

Comment: Ah, thanks for this, so simple, I didn't really expected that `\hspace*` can work in this case, didn't even try it... I thought that `\hspace` and `\vspace` only works in text mode.

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution with the `fleqn` environment from `nccmath`. This environment can take an optional argument to specify at which distance from the left margin it starts:

```
    \documentclass{article}

    \usepackage{mathtools}
    \usepackage{nccmath}
    \DeclareMathOperator{\Hom}{Hom}
    \usepackage{showframe}
    \renewcommand{\ShowFrameLinethickness}{0.4pt}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{fleqn}[4.5em]
    \begin{align*}
        \Hom_C(C \otimes_B (B \otimes_A M), P)
        & \simeq \Hom_B(B \otimes_A M, P)\\
        & \simeq \Hom_A(M, P)\\
        & \simeq \Hom_C(C \otimes_A M, P)
    \end{align*}
    \end{fleqn}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You may liked the following solution:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Hom}{Hom}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\MoveEqLeft[4]
    \Hom_C(C \otimes_B (B \otimes_A M), P)  \\
    & \simeq \Hom_B(B \otimes_A M, P)       \\
    & \simeq \Hom_A(M, P)                   \\
    & \simeq \Hom_C(C \otimes_A M, P)
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```